# Angular 2 Custom validation unit testing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular2-forms, angular2-testing

i'm writing custom angular(Angular 2.0.0) validation, following this guide https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#custom-validation .

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][emailValidator]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: EmailValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class EmailValidatorDirective implements Validator
```

Now i'm trying to add unit test to my custom validation directive.

```
beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EmailComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      de = fixture.debugElement;
      el = de.nativeElement;
      component = de.componentInstance;
      emailField = de.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement;
    });
```

I'm accessing all these object, but no one has any information about the validity of my input. Does anyone has any idea how to access the NgControl of my input inside the Unit Tests, or how can i check for valid/invalid(custom validation) input field.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you need to do is get the injector that has the `NgForm`. It took me a while to figure it out. I thought you could just get it from the `debugElement`, but it looks like you need to get it from it's child<sup>**1**</sup>.

```
let form: NgForm = fixture.debugElement.children[0].injector.get(NgForm);
```

The you can just get individual controls from the form group with

```
let emailControl = form.control.get('email');
expect(emailControl.valid).toBe(true);
```

Or you can just check the form for a specific error

```
expect(form.control.hasError('emailInvalid', ['email'])).toBe(true);
```

Below is a complete test

```
import { Component, forwardRef, Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { TestBed, getTestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule, NG_VALIDATORS, Validator, AbstractControl, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { dispatchEvent } from '@angular/platform-browser/testing/browser_util';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][validEmail]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => EmailValidatorDirective),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
class EmailValidatorDirective implements Validator {

  validate(c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
    if (c.value !== 'peeskillet@stackoverflow.com') {
      return { notPeeskillet: true };
    }
    return null;
  }
}

@Component({
  template: `
    <form>
      <input name="email" [ngModel]="email" validEmail />
    </form>
  `
})
class TestComponent {
  email;
}

describe('component: TestComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule],
      declarations: [TestComponent, EmailValidatorDirective]
    });
  });

  it('should validate', async(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    let comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    let debug = fixture.debugElement;
    let input = debug.query(By.css('[name=email]'));

    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      input.nativeElement.value = 'bad@email.com';
      dispatchEvent(input.nativeElement, 'input');
      fixture.detectChanges();

      let form: NgForm = debug.children[0].injector.get(NgForm);
      let control = form.control.get('email');
      expect(control.hasError('notPeeskillet')).toBe(true);
      expect(form.control.valid).toEqual(false);
      expect(form.control.hasError('notPeeskillet', ['email'])).toEqual(true);

      input.nativeElement.value = 'peeskillet@stackoverflow.com';
      dispatchEvent(input.nativeElement, 'input');
      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(control.hasError('notPeeskillet')).toBe(false);
      expect(form.control.valid).toEqual(true);
      expect(form.control.hasError('notPeeskillet', ['email'])).toEqual(false);
    });
  }));
});
```

---

<sub>**1** - [Found it in the source code tests](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/forms/test/template_integration_spec.ts)</sub>

Comment: `browser_util` has moved to `import { dispatchEvent } from '@angular/platform-browser/testing/src/browser_util';`

Comment: Use the built-in dispatch event instead

Answer (score 2):

The above best answer didn't work for me but I was able to test my custom validator in the following way:

```
const associateRateControl = component.distributionSettingsForm.controls['associateRate'];
associateRateControl.setValue('plus ultra');
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(component.distributionSettingsForm.hasError('noCatalog')).toEqual(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another heads-up on that topic.
[Paul Samsotha answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910017/angular-2-custom-validation-unit-testing/39918775#39918775) I think was correct one and very helpful, but TBH you don't need to import any library. We can use the `nativeElement` `dispatchEvent` and make our lives a little bit easier.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
    const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("input")).nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    input.value = "test";
    input.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it("should display the password strength indicator", () => {
    const form = fixture.componentInstance.myMarvelousForm;
    expect(form.dirty).toBeTruthy();
});
```